# How to check for windows file transfer and start SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server, file, ssis, ssms, file-exists

I am new to SSIS development. I need to run SSIS package after file received to the server.
I am following these steps:
1. First created my SSIS package with Script Task in it to check for file exists. If exists it will continue with next steps in the package.
2. Created SSMS Schedule job to start SSIS package every 10 minutes(recurring) to see if the file is available. Because there is no specific time that file will be transferred to the server. So this job is scheduled for 2 hours window and in that time window every 10min it will start the SSIS package.

My issue is once the file available SSIS completes the process, then how to stop from starting  SSIS package again ? How to tell SSMS that package has already done executing ?

Thanks for your help
SATY

Answer (score 0):

My lazy way would be to update your Agent job. Step 1 is a sql task. Step 2 runs the SSIS package.

The SQL job step will execute a query using `xp_FileExists` to check for the presence of the transferred file.

If the file is not found, have the job reschedule itself for 10 minutes from now and exit reporting success.

If the file is found, then go to step 2 (run the SSIS package).

If you want to put all the logic in SSIS, then you need *something* that you modify to signal you found the file and have processed it. What that something is, depends on what you have handy. Maybe you create a sentinel file that is created (or destroyed) when the job successfully processes a file. Maybe you log it to a dedicated table. Maybe you make a registry key. The sky's the limit, just pick something that is either already an established pattern for your environment or if you're blazing new territory, pick something that those who support this after you can handle. i.e. don't log the event to a service broker queue if no one around you understands how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I like billinkc's thinking, though I'm typically against extended stored procedures (aren't they a bit SQL Server 2000ish?). I'd go with a CLR function for the file exists (like the function in  [this](http://www.wisesoft.co.uk/articles/sql_server_clr_io_utility.aspx) assembly).

Another option you could do is disable the job at the end of the package (after the file is loaded) with an Execute SQL Command.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_name='Your job name',@enabled = 0;
```

Of course, then you'll need to schedule a job to enable that job prior to the beginning of the next window.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_name='Your job name',@enabled = 1;
```

Comment: Brian, Thanks for your help it works perfect. I didn't have creating temp table option, this idea worked for me. I created the script task to check for file exists, If exists then continue with process and at the end of my process i executed the first EXEC you listed. If not exists it will not continue the process and won't execute the EXEC statement at the end. So my job is still active.